# What is the correct way to free GSL matrix?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, free, gsl

I'm using the Gnu Scientific Library in C. From the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html#matrix-allocation):

> ```
> void gsl_matrix_free(gsl_matrix * m)
> ```
>
> This function frees a previously allocated matrix m. If the matrix was
>   created using gsl_matrix_alloc() then the block underlying the matrix
>   will also be deallocated. If the matrix has been created from another
>   object then the memory is still owned by that object and will not be
>   deallocated.

What does this mean? Suppose I have

```
gsl_matrix * get_me_a_matrix(void){
    gls_matrix * out =  gsl_matrix_alloc(10, 10); //here is the allocation
    //assign some values here
    return out;
}
```

And in the main function

```
int main(){
   gsl_matrix * my_matrix = get_me_a_matrix();
   //play around with my matrix here
   gsl_matrix_free(my_matrix);
   //is the memory free now?
```

}

Will a call to `gsl_matrix_free` really free the memory, even if the object has been allocated in another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your code it would work like that. Since you allocated it with `gsl_matrix_alloc`, *you're* to free it with `gsl_matrix_free`. This is not unlike `malloc` and `free`.

The last sentence in the quoted excerpt refers to *you* getting a pointer to a `gsl_matrix` but it points to a memory that is shared or part of the memory owned by another object, that memory will not be freed by `gsl_matrix_free`, but you're to call `gsl_matrix_free` on the pointer nevertheless when you've stopped using it.